# Java cannot find symbol for class in another java file but in the same directory

Tags: java

I am a beginner in learning java, and I am using notepad to learn my basics in java and I can't seem to use the class that I have in another java file(but in the same directory), could someone teach me how to do this ?

For example, in the same directory, I have 2 java files, one is called Shape.java, another is Board.java. In my Shape.java, I have a class called Tetrominoes, now how do I use this Tetrominoes class in my Board.java. I know using import Shape.Tetrominoes will not work.

Below I posted some of the codes that is connected to the class I'm talking about.

Shape.java

```
public class Shape {
    protected enum Tetrominoes { NoShape, OtherShape };
    private Tetrominoes pieceShape;

    public Shape() {
        setShape(Tetrominoes.NoShape);
    }

    public void setShape(Tetrominoes shape) {
        // Codes...
    }

    public Tetrominoes getShape() { return pieceShape; }

}
```

Board.java

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Tetrominoes[] board;

    public Board(Game parent) {
        initBoard(parent);
    }

    // and other codes...
}
```

Everything is fine, except for this error that says "cannot find symbol" pointing to "private Tetrominoes[] board;"

Why is this ? and how should I fix this ? Thank you in advance. Please ask me if anything is unclear or what else I needed to post, I will update my question as soon as I can.

Comment: Use an IDE instead - it makes your programming life easier and less painful.

Comment: Instead of `private Tetrominoes[] board;` use `private Shape.Tetrominoes[]  board;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Tetrominoes` enum is nested in `Shape`. So you *could* refer to it as:

```
private Shape.Tetronminos[] board;
```

... but you'd be better off promoting it to a top-level type, in my view. I'd also suggest calling it `Tetromino` (singular) and making the value names follow Java naming conventions: `NO_SHAPE` and `OTHER_SHAPE` (although I assume those won't be the real values anyway).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Nope, because it's in the same package. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2

Comment: oh, I missed that they are from the same package, +1

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, that did the trick. So I have to ALWAYS refer it to Shape.Tetrominoes each time to use the class? there is no way for me to like import Shape.Tetrominoes and call it just Tetrominoes, just like in IDE ?

Comment: @Charas: Well you *could* do that - but if you don't want to treat it as a nested type, why have you nested it at all? Just make it a top-level type. Note that anything you can do in an IDE you can do in regular source code compiled from the command line too.